# Is there any way to send message from SendEndpoint to exchange with argument alternate-exchange?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm trying to use `ISendEnpoint.Send` method to send message to RabbitMq exchange that have argument `alternate-exchange` and I didn't find any way to set value for this argument.
If I don't specify this argument, I catch this exception:

> "RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP
>   operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer,
>   code=406, text="PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg
>   'alternate-exchange' for exchange 'target_queue' in vhost '/':
>   received none but current is the value 'norouted'".

How to specify this argument?

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the publish topology of a message, such that the destination exchange specifies an alternate exchange and queue, so that published messages without a valid destination are delivered to the alternate.

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/tests/MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Tests/AlternateExchange_Specs.cs

Comment: I need to **send** message, not to publish. And want to set all arguments for destination exchange in uri for `ISendEndpointProvider.GetSendEndpoint` method. But as I found in method `RabbitMqSendTopology.GetSendSettings` argument `alternate-exchange` isn't parsing here. Is there another way to config destination exchange?

Comment: No, which is why I tried to explain to you how it works using publish. If you know how RMQ works you know that send and publish are basically the same in RMQ, they both send to exchanges. I gave you the way to do it.